# Can we make promise to wait until resolved and onreject call back the promise again

Tags: javascript

I'm learning about `Promise`'s and have a little doubt assuming that I want to get resolved status out of `Promise`s
and not want reject! Can I just call back the promise function inside
 catch to make sure that I get only approved value! Is that possible or
 will it throw an error or goes to loop iteration

```
let promisetocleantheroom = new Promise(function cleanroom(resolve, reject) {
    //code to clean the room
    //then as a result the clean variable will have true or flase
    if (clean == "true") {
        resolve("cleaned");
    } else {
        reject("not cleaned");
    }
});
promisetocleantheroom.then(function cleanroom(fromResolve) {
    // wait for the function to finish only then it would run the function then
    console.log("the room is " + fromResolve);
}).catch(function cleanroom(fromReject) {
    //calling back the promise again
    cleanroom(); 
});
```

Comment: See https://javascript.info/promise-chaining . You can chain the promises.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having higher order functions and recursivity, here is my proposed solution.

First you need to wrap your promise in a function to recreate it when it fails. Then you can pass it to `retryPromiseMaker` with a partial error handler to create another function that will act as retrier. And this function will return a Promise that will fulfill only if one of the inner promises fulfills.

Sounds complicated but I promise you it is not!

```js
const retryPromiseMaker = (fn, errorfn = null) => {

  const retryPromise = (retries = 3, err = null) => {

    if (err) {
      errorfn(err);
    }

    if (retries === 0) {
      return Promise.reject(err);
    }
    return fn()
      .catch(err => retryPromise(retries - 1, err));
  };
  return retryPromise;
}

const cleanTheRoom = (resolve, reject) => {
  // simulate cleaning as a probability of 33%
  const clean = Math.random() < 0.33;

  setTimeout(() => {
    if (clean) {
      resolve("cleaned");
    } else {
      reject("not cleaned");
    }
  }, Math.random() * 700 + 200);
};

const promiseToCleanTheRoom = () => new Promise(cleanTheRoom);

const logStatus = end => value => {
  let text = '';
  if (end){
    text += "at the end ";
  }
  text += "the room is " + value;
  console.log(text);
};



retryPromiseMaker(promiseToCleanTheRoom, logStatus(false))(4)
  .then(logStatus(true),logStatus(true));
```